# Haskell Arbitrary Instance of Higher Order type

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have the type and it is an instance of SemiGroup.
I want to write a quickCheck method to ensure that it is correct.
How do I create an Arbitrary instance of this type?

```
newtype Combine a b =
  Combine { unCombine :: a -> b }

instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (Combine a b) where
  x <> y = Combine $ \n -> unCombine x n <> unCombine y n

instance (Q.Arbitrary a, Num a) => Q.Arbitrary (Combine a b) where
  arbitrary = do
    a <- Q.arbitrary
    return $ Combine (\n -> Sum(n+1)) a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal fix is to turn on `FlexibleInstances` and write:

```
instance (Q.Arbitrary a, Num a) => Q.Arbitrary (Combine a (Sum a)) where
  arbitrary = do
    a <- Q.arbitrary :: Q.Gen ()
    return $ Combine (\n -> Sum(n+1))
```

However, this is a bit unsatisfactory: I observe that `a` is completely unused (hence has to be manually given a type signature!), and the distribution over functions is kind of boring, since it returns the function `(+1)` (up to newtype wrapping) with probability 1. (Perhaps you wanted `return $ Combine (\n -> Sum (n+a))`? But even then the class of functions you can produce this way is a little bit boring. I'm not sure what you really meant, and I won't spend long speculating.)

If you want to do it right, you should produce a random output for each input. This is pretty convenient with the [`universe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) package:

```
import Data.Universe
import Data.Universe.Instances.Reverse
instance (Ord a, Finite a, Q.Arbitrary b) => Q.Arbitrary (Combine a b) where
  arbitrary = Combine <$> sequenceA (const Q.arbitrary)
```

As a side benefit, this does not require any extensions. However, you should be careful to choose input types with small domains -- `Combine Bool (Sum Int)` should be fine, or even `Combine Word8 (Sum Word8)`, but if you try to test a property on a type like `Combine Int (Sum Int)` you will be sorry!

Comment: This looks like what I want. I'm new to haskell and trying to figure out how to add those dependencies to my single file, using stack. Without a yaml or cabal file. When I figure this out I will mark your answer and upvote when I prove it works. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: @mac10688 If you're not using a stack file or cabal file, you will need to install the package with `cabal install`. You need to use a stack file or cabal file to have explicit dependencies.

Comment: @DavidYoung I was able to use stack ghci --resolver nightly-2015-11-10 --package universe QuickCheck. Now, I am working through some compiling errors.

Comment: It took a while but I was finally able to prove you right. I did have to make an instance of Arbitrary for Sum and my Combine newtype needed to derive Eq and Show.